# Merge two dictionaries from user input through a function

Tags: python, function, dictionary

I'm new in Python and I am writing a function which merges two dictionaries from different users input. It works but it seems to me that my code is unnecessary long and cumbersome. Is there a way to make it more simple and fluid? Here the code:

```
key1 = int(input("Give an integer as first key"))
key2 = int(input("Give an integer as second key"))

value1 = input("Give a a first value")
value2 = input("Give a second value")


class_list1 = {}
class_list2 = {}

class_list1[key1] = value1

class_list2[key2] = value2


def merge_dictionaries(x,y):
    z = {**x,**y}
    print("The merged dictionary is : ")
    return z
    
    

print(merge_dictionaries(class_list1, class_list2))
```

Output:

```
Give an integer as first key 1
Give an integer as second key 2
Give a a first value value1
Give a second value value2
The merged dictionary is : 
{1: 'value1', 2: 'value2'}
```

Comment: Other than `return {**x,**y}`, you can't be much shorter than what you already have. By the way, your `print` statement in `merge_dictionary` isn't printing out anything useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is some slight trimming of your original (simplifying the function and wrapping the `input` lines where possible):

```
class_list1 = {}
class_list2 = {}

key1 = int(input("Give an integer as first key"))
key2 = int(input("Give an integer as second key"))

class_list1[key1] = input("Give a a first value")
class_list2[key2] = input("Give a second value")

def merge_dictionaries(x,y):
    return {**x,**y}

print("The merged dictionary is : {}".format(merge_dictionaries(class_list1, class_list2)))
```

The above is what I would do to save lines while keeping the logic of your original code.

If you are open to other approaches, you could take one `input` and then use `split` to dice it into the pieces needed to create a dictionary.  The code here is shorter and can take variable amounts of key:value pairs, but the `input` has a more complicated structure:

```
s = input('Enter int:string pairs, separated by commas\n').split(',')
d = {int(p.split(':')[0]) : p.split(':')[-1] for p in s}
print("The merged dictionary is : {}".format(d))
```

So an `input` of `1:a,2:b,3:c` gives `{1: 'a', 2: 'b', 3: 'c'}`

Answer (score 2):

Try the following

```
key1 = int(input("Give an integer as first key"))
key2 = int(input("Give an integer as second key"))
x= y= {}
x[key1]=input("Give a a first value")
y[key2]=input("Give a second value")
print({**x,**y})
```

Answer (score 2):

You could save the user inputs directly in the dictionary without merging:

```
userStorage = {}
for inputNum in range(2):
    # Temporary variables
    _key, _value = None, None
    
    while not (_key and _value):
        # both variables must have a value!
        # 'validate' at least the key as integer
        try:
            _key = int(input("Give an integer as key#%d:" % inputNum))
        except:
            print("No integer entered!")
            continue
        _value = input("Give a value for key#%d:" % inputNum)
        
        if _key and _value:
            userStorage[_key] = _value
            break
print(userStorage)
```

Output:

```
Give an integer as key#0:asd
No integer entered!
Give an integer as key#0:9
Give a value for key#0:foo
Give an integer as key#1:10
Give a value for key#1:bar
{9: 'foo', 10: 'bar'}
```

Note the 'shortest' version could be (but now the code is prone to wrong user inputs):

```
userInput = lambda x, y: int(input("Give an integer as key#%d:" % x)) if y == 0 else input("Give a value for key#%d:" % x)
userStorage = {userInput(x, 0): userInput(x, 1) for x in range(2)}
print(userStorage)
```

Output:

```
Give an integer as key#0:87
Give a value for key#0:foo
Give an integer as key#1:88
Give a value for key#1:baz
{87: 'foo', 88: 'baz'}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code isn't too long, it's not refactored.
Have a look at code refactoring.

Create a function for acquiring input, one to create the dictionary and use a main function

```
         def merge_dictionaries(x,y):
            z = {**x,**y}
            print("The merged dictionary is : {0} ".format(z))
            return z

         def main:
             class_list1,class_list2 = function_input_dictionary() #function that returns dicts
             key1,key2 = function_input_key() #function that returns input of key
             value1,value2 = function_input_value() # function that returns values
             print(merge_dictionaries(class_list1, class_list2))

#look for design patterns and double return of parameters
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following one you will find it helpful because in my example you can simply merge more than 2 dictionaries by modifying the variable called `length`

### Example

```
length = 2
key = 0
value = ''
class_list = {}
for i in range(1, length):
    key = int(input(f"Give an integer as {i} key: "))
    value = input(f"Give a a {i} value: ")
    class_list[key] = value


def merge_dictionaries(x,y):
    print("The merged dictionary is : ")
    return {**x,**y}
    
print(merge_dictionaries(class_list, class_list))
```

Answer (score -1):

try creating dictionary like this instead of using different variables. and it will not change the expected output.

```
class_list1[int(input("Give an integer as first key"))] = input("Give a a first value")

class_list2[int(input("Give an integer as second key"))] = input("Give a second value")
```

Comment: one line indenting commands like in scala or functional programming isn't what is needed here.
He's asking help for a better readability in the code, putting all in one line, sometimes makes code harder to read.